# How can I create a subdomain to a Facebook page running on CloudFlare

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to add a subdomain to my website for an Android community Facebook page, using CloudFlare on my domain and subdomain. Please tell me how I might do that.

Answer (score 1):

First add a subdomain to your website as detailed here:  [CloudFlare Support:  How do I add a subdomain?](https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22060688-How-do-I-add-a-subdomain-)

Then create a permanent 301 redirect for the subdomain you created by going to the menu in your account and selecting `Page rules` and defining the Facebook URL to redirect the subdomain to, as covered here:  [Make 301 Redirect for Subdomain in Cloudflare](http://howexplain.com/web/make-301-redirect-for-subdomain-in-cloudflare-with-www-without/)